# PhpStorm with xdebug doesn't stop on breakpoints. Log says "Xdebug protocol doesn't support command"

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 19.10 running in Virtualbox on Windows 7.

I have the latest PhpStorm: 2019.3 (running on Windows).

I have PHP 7.3.11, with opcode disabled, running with nginx.

I have xdebug 2.7.2.

I've done the configurations like in another machine with older versions of PhpStorm, PHP, and xdebug, which worked.

When I try to debug - PhpStorm doesn't stop on breakpoints.
I've enabled PhpStorm's debug log. I saw messages about the connection succeeding, and then:

```
INFO - n.XdebugConnectionConfigurator - Xdebug protocol doesn't support command: 'feature_set -i 5 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1'
```

I enabled xdebug logging, and saw some success messages, and then this:

```
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" status="starting" reason="ok"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>
```

So it seems to me like PhpStorm is actually trying to send an unsupported command.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and can share a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it seems to me like PhpStorm is actually trying to send an unsupported command.

**Yes and No at the same time:** `resolved_breakpoints` feature (command) is supported since Xdebug **2.8**

AFAIK that command is sent since PhpStorm 2019.3 (2019.2.x and older do not try to use it).

> Has anyone encountered this issue before and can share a workaround?

It does not affect your debug session in that Xdebug 2.7.x and older versions, at all. There is simply no need for any workarounds here.

Comment: Thank you, that's good feedback, but unfortunately debugging simply doesn't work. Breakpoints are not hit. Do you mean that my actual problems are not really related to this, and in fact there is a separate issue going on that I haven't identified yet?

Comment: @obe Yes, it has to be something else as it still works just fine here (Windows 10; PhpStorm 2019.2.x & 2019.3.1; local PHP 7.3 x64 nts). I suggest creating new question and provide your setup/configs + Xdebug log there.

Comment: ok, after seeing your answer I tried to rollback to an older PhpStorm. The specific error disappeared, but debugging still didn't work. It's so frustrating that even today after 10-20 years of "maturing" in the ecosystem it's still so difficult to get such a straightforward setup to work (my Googling of this revealed that I'm hardly the only one who hit some wall with it). Every few years I try a clean setup and every time I'm punished with bizarre issues / incompatibilities / unclear or undocumented configurations / etc :(

Comment: This could be your firewall, could be wrong Xdebug config, maybe even some misconfiguration at your VirtualBox level. Without seeing your setup/logs I cannot say what that might be (+ there always will be some nuances that ppl ignore because they seem not important etc). I personally did not had any issues setting it up in my environments... but your might be very different to mine.